# How do I view all "stale" files within Accurev folder?

Tags: accurev

Is it possible to search for/view all "stale" files within the currently selected directories. N.B. I'm using the acgui tool rather than command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on File -> Update Preview. When the process completes, click the "View Full Log" button in the dialog.

Comment: It was more that I was looking to see the stale files within the actual acgui tool rather than having to look at a log output.